# document.invalidate gives empty json as response

Tags: express, mongoose

I wanted to check if the `body` in a document is unique. If not unique give appropriate error.

```
NewsSchema.pre("save", true, function (next: any, done: any) {
    var self = this;
    News.findOne({body: self.body}, "body", function (err: any, body: string) {
        if(err)
             done(err);
        else if(body) {
            self.invalidate("body", "the news body already exists", self.body);
            done(new Error("the news body already exists"));
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
   });
});
```

When intentionally giving a duplicate `body`. It returns with an empty json. Whereas I was expecting it to be:

```
{ 
    message: 'Validation failed',
    name: 'ValidationError',
    errors:
    { 
        size:
        {
            message: 'the news body already exists',
            name: 'ValidatorError',
            path: 'body',
            type: 'String',
            value: 'some string'
         } 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `validate()` to check if it is valid or not.

```
var self = this; //type document
...
self.invalidate("body", "the news body already exists", self.body);

//use validate() to check the validity
self.validate(function(err){
    console.log(err);//this will give you your expected results.
});
```

Comment: i tried your solution. but still it did not work. i have updated the problem.

Comment: You are trying to use findOne in `pre('save')`. Are you sure you will be able to find that document even before it is actually saved? That will always give you no such document present. Assuming  body is `unique`

Comment: Checking the mongodb, the new document is not created at all when duplicate. When giving a `unique` body, the document is created. The only problem is I am not getting error just empty json.

Comment: I am telling you that, if you have `unique` body, how will you be able to find it using `findOne` in your `pre('save')`, before you have actually `saved` it in the `collection`. Thus, there is no result from the `findOne` query and thus `empty json`.

Comment: When a `unique` body is given, it saves the document as expected and returns a success json. But it is only giving empty json when not unique which is not what I want. Hope I clarified it.